# How to predict physics movement

Tags: physics

How to predict the movement of the body when a force is applied on it like in the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.game.basketballshoot

I have attached screen shot as reference.[image]

Comment: You already asked that question http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/show-path-of-a-body-of-where-it-should-go-after-linear-impulse-is-applied

Comment: And another: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/projectile-motion-arrow

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to find out how a physics-based sequence would turn out is to simulate it. Sample the positions as you go and draw indicators on suitably spaced places.

This works regardless of the model you're using, may it be an actual simulation or some simplified model like "follow this parabolic path".